# Get() и Set() методы

Tags: java

Зачем делать private переменные и при этом создавать для них гэттеры и сеттеры?

Можно же просто public оставить? Как бы закрываем доступ от изменений и тут же даем этот доступ из сеттера и геттера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Геттеры и сеттеры - это про безопасность. Если вы оставляете открытые поля, и работаете с ними напрямую, то они не защищены от неожиданных данных.

Например, вы создали объект, и у него есть поле `int age`. Вас устроит возраст `-10000 лет`? Вот тут и придут на помощь сеттеры, это полноценные методы, в которых вы производите в случае необходимости проверки на передаваемые в них данные (значения).

Ну а геттеры, если вы догадались, чтобы получить значение из закрытого поля.

Comment: ну так я через Set.age 10 000 сделаю этот возраст. Или нет?

Comment: @МаксимАлексеенко через сеттер вы можете ограничить любым возрастом... хоть 10 000 лет, хоть 100. Я вам привел простой пример, этим не заканчивается фантазия проверок.

Comment: Ни че не понимаю, как это ограничить если нет ограничения. Мы добавили в класс Set() для чего либо, где тут ограничение, это означает, что через Set можно установить что угодно без всяких ограничений

Comment: либо это при голой конструкции Set()? Типа просто Set() никто не делает, а делают составные Set-ы, типа Set(if a <10 бла бла... ?

Comment: @МаксимАлексеенко В setter-е Вы можете написать любую логику, не позволяющую устанавливать бессмысленные значения.

Comment: @Igor но если там нет логики, то доступ открыт?

Comment: @МаксимАлексеенко Кхм, кхм, если нет логики - то установится любое значение. "Доступ открыт" - что это значит? Нет речи ни о каком "доступе". Вызывающий код никогда не узнает, что представляет собой механизм хранения этого значения.

Comment: Я имею ввиду есть какая либо переменная "А" с модификатором private у нее значение "100" так же есть в классе Get() и Set(). Так вот из другого класса можно поменять ее на 200. Как бы есть private но при этот можно делать изменения

Comment: @МаксимАлексеенко Но внеший код не знает ни про какую переменную.

Comment: @igor что такое внешний код?

Comment: @МаксимАлексеенко Код снаружи Вашего класса, который вызывает гетер и сетер.